# How to get the last value of a column from a csv file.Note-In case of file with just header it should give value as 0,rest scenario is working

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Using below command[This works when file has header with records-Suggest changes in this command.]

```
tail -1 input.csv| awk -F "|" '{print $1}' >> output.csv
```

Scenario 1:(Please suggest-when there is only header)

Input.csv

```
ErrorCount|ErrorMessage
```

Output.csv(Expected)

```
0
```

Scenario 2: Working fine.

Input.csv

```
ErrorCount|ErrorMessage
1|Bad Request
2|Precision higher
3|Invalid address
```

Output.csv(Its working fine)

```
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ cat input1.csv
ErrorCount|ErrorMessage

$ awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{x=0;} NR>1{x=$1;} END{print x;}' input1.csv 
0

$ cat input2.csv
ErrorCount|ErrorMessage
1|Bad Request
2|Precision higher
3|Invalid address

$ awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{x=0;} NR>1{x=$1;} END{print x;}' input2.csv
3
```

- `BEGIN{x=0;}`: set the default value to be printed
- `NR>1{...}`: only execute that block *after* the first line
- `NR>1{x=$1;}`: set the value to be printed to be the first field
- `END{print x;}`: on script exit, print the value

---

And since you now need to combine multiple files in one row of output,

```sh
$ for fn in input2.csv input2.csv input2.csv ; do
    awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{x=0;} NR>1{x=$1;} END{printf x "|";}' "${fn}"
done | sed -e "s/|$//"
3|3|3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it is really helpful.just few more queries: I am extracting the column values in similar manner from total 3 files and want to display those values in a single file in a single record with pipe delimeted.I already have that output file with header created manually.I just want output like this in second row. 3|0|2

Comment: Testscript.sh                                                                                                                          cat Sales.csv | awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{x=0;} NR>1{x=$1;} END{print x;}' >> output.csv
cat Product.csv | awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{x=0;} NR>1{x=$1;} END{print x;}' >> output.csv
cat Bill.csv | awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{x=0;} NR>1{x=$1;} END{print x;}' >> output.csv

Comment: Right now the output is coming in different lines.I need them in a single line with pipe delimeter

Comment: I do not understand what you expect. This gives the exact output you show in your question, you've previously made no mention of a pipe-delimiter in the output.

Comment: Yes correct.Initially i didn't mention as there was just one file.Later on checking I found 3 similar files.So out of the three files,one value from each file with the command you suggested. Now I want it to store in a output file with pipe delimeter in a single row.Hope I would have made things more clear now.